# How to call an Objective-C category method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How would you call an Objective-C category method like this in Swift?

```
+(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex alpha:(float)alpha;
```

Comment: Class.colorWithHexString("#ffffff", 1)

Comment: That method must be from a category?  I cannot find a reference to it on the web.

Comment: I believe it is `Class.colorWithHexString("#ffffff", alpha:1)`. I don’t know if the named parameter is optional or required, but even if it is optional, I would prefer it. (Sort-of) named parameters were one thing that made Objective-C nicer than C, and now it seems that Swift has true named parameters, so I would encourage taking advantage of them.

Comment: @trojanfoe it doesn't have to be a category it could be an class method from any class.

Comment: But using Swift with Objective-C categories is a more interesting question...

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it is. Although, I assume it would be the same. I'm not sure why this is getting down voted when this is a legitimate question which I can't find in the Apple provided eBook.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I don't understand what you mean by "now it seems that Swift has true named parameters"?  Hasn't C always had named parameters?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Depends on how you declare the function. If you declare it like `colorWithHexString(hex: String, alpha: Int)` my answer is correct, if you declare it like `colorWithHexString(hex: String, #alpha: Int)` your answer is correct.

Comment: @trojanfoe Oops, I thought the order of Swift’s named parameters didn’t matter, but apparently it does. And @leadros’s `Class.colorWithHexString("#ffffff", 1)` is also correct, because parameter names are optional.

Comment: Obviously include it in your bridging header file, or it won't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler automatically looks for common ObjC naming patterns and substitutes Swift patterns in their place. An ObjC class method that returns an instance of the class (and is named a certain way, it looks like) gets turned into a Swift convenience initializer.

If you have the ObjC method (defined by a custom category):

```
 + (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hex alpha:(float)alpha;
```

The compiler generates the Swift declaration:

```
convenience init(hexString: String?, alpha: CFloat)
```

And you call it like this:

```
let color = UIColor(hexString: "#ffffff", alpha: 1.0)
```

---

And in Swift 2.0 or later, you can use the `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro to make ObjC factory methods that don't match the naming pattern import to Swift as initializers. e.g.:

```
@interface UIColor(Hex)
+ (UIColor *)hexColorWithString:(NSString *)string
NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(hexString:));
@end

// imports as
extension UIColor {
    init(hexString: String)
}
```

Comment: Just for complete list of variants: in case you have smth like `+ (AAPLAPI *)registerAcctount:(NSString*)username password:(NSString *)password;` in Obj-c and want to call it from Swift, the call would look like this: `AAPLAPI.registerAccount(usernameTextField?.text, password: passwordTextField?.text)`

Comment: Make sure you also should add your category file to the '<YouApp>-Bridging-Header.h'. In another case, swift code do not see your category.