# Using Objective-C extension classes in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I am trying to write new features of my Objective-C project in Swift. I have an existing Objective-C file called NSString+Extensions defined like so

```
@interface NSString (Extensions)
```

The file is named as NSString.Extensions.h. I have some application specific instance methods (ex: stringByRemovingSpecialCharacters). I have added a header file (bridging header), specific it in Swift Compiler - Code Generation in my project settings. I added the #import "NSString+Extensions.h" in that header file. But none of the methods in the extension file can be called from Swift file. How do I make use of this extension file in Swift? I have more extension files - NSData+Encryption.h etc, that I would like to use as well.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006264/how-to-call-an-objective-c-category-method-in-swift ?

Comment: I have used extension files like this from Swift code. Can you post the contents of your file? One problem I had in Xcode 6.0.1 was that if an imported .h file contained a duplicate definition of a method, anything declared after the duplicate method definition was not visible in Swift. So, if your .h happens to be long, check for duplicate definitions and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a objective-C file to a swift project xcode will ask if you want to add an objective -c bridging header, to which you reply yes. You should then import your files in the bridging file and this will allow you to call them from your swift files. PS you can then delete the objective-C file which has no use now.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. I can use my custom Obj-C classes that way (I updated my question to say bridging header just to be clear) but I can't use a obj-C file that is an extension of the Obj-C primary or native (how do you call it?) class ex: NSString. My custom class is - NSString (Extensions) or NSString+Extensions.h. So that if I import that header, I can do NSString *str = @"foo%&$%&"; str = [str stringByRemovingSpecialCharacters];

Comment: I don't think you want to delete your Objective-C file. The bridging header has an import statement for this file, and the file needs to exist.

Comment: No just the dummy one you create to prompt xcode to build the bridging header.